# Convergence almost everywhere vs. convergence in $L^1$

Tags: probability-theory

This is Exercise 6.1.2 from *Achim Klenke: »Probability Theory — A Comprehensive Course«.*

> *Exercise:* Give an example of a sequence that
>
> (i) converges in $L^1$ but not almost everywhere,
>
> (ii) converges almost everywhere but not in $L^1$.

*Solution:*

Let $\bigl(\Omega, \mathbb{B}(\Omega), \mu\bigl)$ be the measure space with $\Omega = [0,1]$, and $\mu$ the Borel measure. Let $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $d(x, y) = |x-y|$ the metric on $E$. We will look at $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)-\mathcal{B}(E)$-measurable maps.

(i) Define
\begin{equation*}
A_1 := \biggl[0, \frac{1}{2}\biggr),\; A_2 := \biggl[\frac{1}{2}, 1\biggr), \; A_3 := \biggl[0, \frac{1}{3}\biggr), \; A_4 := \biggl[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\biggr), \; \dots
\end{equation*} then $_{A_n}$ converges in $L^1$ to $0$, because $\| _{A_n} - 0 \|_1 = \int_\Omega | _{A_n} - 0| \, d\mu = \mu(A_n) \overset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$, but not almost surely, because for any $0 \leq \omega < 1$ we have $_{A_n}(\omega) = 1$ for an infinite number of $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

(ii) Let $B_n := \bigl[0, \frac{1}{n}\bigr]$ and $f_n = n _{B_n}$. Then for any $0 < \omega \leq 1$ there is an $n$ so that $\frac{1}{n} < \omega$ which means $d(f_n(\omega),0)\overset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$, so $f_n$ converges everywhere except on $\{0\}$, which is a null set, to $0$.

But $f_n$ doesn't converge in $L^1$ to $0$:
\begin{equation*}
  \|f_n - 0 \|_1 = \int_{\Omega} |n \, _{B_n} - 0| \, d\mu = n\, \mu(B_n) = n\cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1\, .
\end{equation*}

---

Could you please check if my examples are correct?

Thank you!

Comment: I like the second one for sure. That is the classic example. For the first one, I don't think $\mu(A_n)=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$. In particular look at your last example: $\mu(A_4)\ne\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Your examples are good, and certainly $\mu(A_n)\to0$ in the first case but *not* $\mu(A_n)=\frac1n$. If you don't want to explicitly calculate $\mu(A_n)$ in general you could easily find a bound which tends to zero.